# UIView Shadow glitch

Tags: ios, uiview

I tried to rebuild the [cardView](https://s14-eu5.startpage.com/cgi-bin/serveimage?url=https:%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FeZm_rr7Gcsw%2Fmaxresdefault.jpg&sp=ab197a7fc66ac0e623618778ad820f4b) from Android in my iOS app. I am using multi-os-engine this is why my code is in java **but** it is almost the same in obj-c or swift.

I wrote this method to add a shadow to my UIViews.

```
public static void addCardView(UIView view) {
    long cornerRadius = 2;
    int shadowOffsetWidth = 0;
    int shadowOffsetHeight = 3;
    float shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
    UIColor shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor();

    UIBezierPath shadowPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPathWithRoundedRectCornerRadius(view.bounds(), cornerRadius);
    view.layer().setCornerRadius(cornerRadius);
    view.layer().setMasksToBounds(false);
    view.layer().setShadowColor(shadowColor.CGColor());
    view.layer().setShadowOffset(new CGSize(shadowOffsetWidth, shadowOffsetHeight));
    view.layer().setShadowOpacity(shadowOpacity);
    view.layer().setShadowPath(shadowPath.CGPath());
}
```

When using this with older iPhones this works perfect. But when Using iPhone XR or similar ones, I get the following glitch (right bottom corner):

[image]

Any advice on this?

Comment: Check if the `frame` of the `layer` has the correct size when you call `addCardView`.

Comment: @carsten How would I check that? It is verys weird because the upper right corner is correct, so is the bottom left one.

Comment: Oh okay I fixed it by calling my `addCardView` in "viewWillLoadSubviews".

Comment: Okay no, it is even weirder. When calling it there the problem is fixed in some of my activities but not in others.

Comment: just check if `view.frame` when calling `addCardView` is the same as in e.g. `viewDidAppear(_:)`.

Comment: @carsten I checked and for one case it was different. After calling `addCardView` in `viewDidAppear` it fixed it. But in another case, where I load an UIViewController in a ContainerView, the frame width is always the same. But obv. too small. I don't understand why.

Comment: if I'm not wrong its taking the initial width from the storyboard/xib and when calling your method to early it might be the case, that the view layout is not adjusted to the device size yet, therefore you end up with having layout issues.

Comment: A combination with `view.LayoutIfNeeded()` succeeded. But I still don't really understand the process behind it. Why the frame size is different.